# Get the list of user variables from Octopus

Tags: octopus-deploy

we have Octopus-2.0.
We stored the service credentials (they are per machine) in octopus user variable.
I need to create these login in SQL server as well.

For Example service login name "machine1_service1" stored as variable name. and password of that login is stored under column Variable Value in octopus.

so far i know that to any variable value from octopus we need to provide exact variable name. but in this case I actually need to get list of all these variables.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: You could filter out any variable that does not begin with `Octopus` or `env:`

Answer (score 8):

Yes.

Octopus variables are accessible from a dictionary object that can be enumerated. If you follow a naming convention you could query the dictionary using powershell with something like the following. This would be called from within a custom step or somewhere where you can write your own powershell e.g. a PostDeploy.ps1 script in the *.nuget* file

Let's say the variables are defined like this

[image]

You can use this powershell to get to them and enumerate round them

```
# Get service accounts
$serviceAccounts = $OctopusParameters.keys | ? {$_ -like "service-*"}
write-host "Accounts found:" $serviceAccounts.count

foreach($account in $serviceAccounts)
{
    write-host "Account: $account"

    $password = $OctopusParameters[$account]
    write-host "Password: $password"
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: as you mentioned already this code is good if naming conventions have been used in setting Name but in our case naming convention does not include any fixed string in name. but your suggestion is good.

Comment: @Matt: do we have similar script in bash also?